# how to use javascript event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 2 col layout, on the left i have a button that says show code and on the right i have some html.
The above is repeat numerous time so i have a list of buttons that i want related to the "widget" next to it.
If i click on each button, i would like to show the innerHTML of the element to the right in an alert box.
My right column html widgets are a class called "mywidgets", and my buttons to the left have a class called "showcode"

how would I go about showing the code of the related box to the right on click of button to the left in javascript or jquery?

if I do something like:

```
var showthem = document.getElementsByClassName('mywidgets');
for (var i=0; i < widgetBits.length; i++) {

 };
```

but I get confused on how to count each button and each class in the seperate area, then show the code on click.

I was also thinking about something similar to below but again I get confused on how to utilize "this"/each item clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("mywidgets").clone().appendTo("myareofchoce");
});
});
```

**HTML:**

left area :

```
 <div class="container marginBTM10">
<div class="row">      

  <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-10 col-md-10 bgColor_FFF padding10">
    <h2>Widget 1</h2>
   <div class="highlight">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " onclick="widgets()">get code</button>
```

right hand area :

```
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
    <!-- widget 1 starts-->
    <div class="sortable bgColor_FFF mywidgets">
      <div class="padding10">

        <a href="#">stuff</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- widget 1 ends-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post list of widget and button code for html ?

Comment: <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="widgets()">get code</button>

Comment: <div class="mywidgets">html code etc</div>

Comment: the above multiple times

Comment: Just edit your question and paste html code there.

Comment: Referring to your html code there's no ` class="mywidgets"`???

Comment: `$("mywidgets").clone().appendTo("myareofchoce");` should be `$(".mywidgets").clone().appendTo(".myareofchoce");` Adding `.` before the selectors. And where is `myareofchoce`?

Comment: sorry i added in extra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/wne6rnda/1/

to connect buttons and widgets must be used in a single tag. 
in this case: widget has id  and corresponding button has data-id with same value

**HTML:**

buttons:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm get_class" data-id="#mywidgets1">
...
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm get_class" data-id="#mywidgets2">
...
```

widgets:

```
div class="sortable bgColor_FFF mywidgets" id="mywidgets1">
...
div class="sortable bgColor_FFF mywidgets" id="mywidgets2">
...
```

**JQ**

```
$('.get_class').click(function () {
    //get id of selected widget
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    //get selected widget
    var $widget = $(id);
    //clon and add selected widget
    $widget.clone().appendTo(".myareofchoce");

})
```

**UPDATE: 2**

http://jsfiddle.net/wne6rnda/9/

```
$('.get_class').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var $widget = $(id);

    var html=$widget.html();

    //solution 1 - output to the textarea
    var txt=$(".myareofchoce2").val();
    $(".myareofchoce2").val(txt+"\r\n"+html);

    //solution 2 - use <xmp> tag
    html='<xmp >'+html+'</xmp >';    
    $(".myareofchoce").append(html);
})
```

Comment: how do i display the HTML for the result? currently this fix only show the text output (i need to see tags etc)